# Push different UIView for each row of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to push a new view when I select a row.

```
let identifiers:[String] = ["vc1", "vc2", "vc3", "vc4", "vc5"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let identifier = identifiers[indexPath.row]
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(identifier)") as! UINavigationController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

All the different views called with this tableView have their own class and Storyboard ID.

At the moment I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'testApp.CalculatorViewController' to 'UINavigationController'

Comment: Can you just write `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(identifier)")`?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, i could but and it would partially work. But I would like to get the navigationController on the next page and if i do that the navigationController isn't there.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment below, push and present are different things...but the main point is that you can't call something a `UINavigationController` if that's not what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to cast UIViewController to UINavigationController.

Please try this. This may help you.

```
let identifiers:[String] = ["vc1", "vc2", "vc3", "vc4", "vc5"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let identifier = identifiers[indexPath.row]
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(identifier)") as! UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: If I replace the UINavigationController, yes the page is properly called but I don't have my NavigationController anymore on the next View.
Do I need to add it manually on each ViewController or is there a way to generate it automatically before?

Comment: You simply have to set UINavigationController as Initial View Controller. And use push segue rather then present (Modal).

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear on push instead of show.

So i replaced the last line of your code with:
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

If you care I can select your answer if you replace the line.
Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I edit my answer and replace present view Controller with push view Controller. Please mark it as accepted.